# How to assign inner JSON to object inside promise?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

In Angular2 "Tour of Heroes" tutorial it is shown how to assign JSON to variable inside a promise. 
What if my JSON is complex:

JSON:

```
let complexMessage = [{
      "heroes":[
      {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
      {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
      {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
      {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
      {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
      {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
      {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
      {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
      {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
      {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'}
      ]
      ,"numHeroes": 9
      ,"messages":[
        {message: "aaa", args:[]},
        {message: "bbb", args:[]}
      ]
    }];
```

The following Typescript doesn't work for multidimensional JSON:

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json())
               .catch(this.handleError);
```

and then:

```
getHeroes() {
    this.heroService
        .getHeroes()
        .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes)
        .catch(error => this.error = error);
  }
```

Does anyone know how to assign inner "heroes" to this.heroes?
(the original  code is at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html)

Comment: You should not assign to `this.…` inside a promise callback at all. Store the promise itself, and call `.then` when you need to access the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to receive the heroes from this json you can do it like this:

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json()[0].heroes)
               .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the `heroes` array not full response to the `this.heroes` you will get whatever you want, or as alternate just send desired array at the time of http call, try this one-

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json())
               .catch(this.handleError);

getHeroes() {
    this.heroService
        .getHeroes()
        .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes[0].heroes) // here take first key of array and you will get heroes as return
        .catch(error => this.error = error); 
  }
```